# How to do some work when push notification arrives?

Tags: ios, objective-c, apple-push-notifications, ios9

I have an application, I got the push notifications, but I would like to do that if the device got a push notification my application do some work in the background without user interaction.
Now I can do some work if the user tap on the notification, but it's not enough efficient for me.

Answer (score 1):

**1. In Info.plist set UIBackgroundModes to remote-notification**

```
<key>UIBackgroundModes</key>
<array>
    <string>remote-notification</string>
</array>
```

**2.  You need to implement following method in ApplicationDelegate**

```
- (void)application:(UIApplication *)application didReceiveRemoteNotification:(NSDictionary *)userInfo fetchCompletionHandler:(void (^)(UIBackgroundFetchResult result))handler
{

   //Success
    handler(UIBackgroundFetchResultNewData);
}
```

**3. Send Push notification with content-available: 1 so it will work like silent**

```
aps {
content-available: 1
alert: {...}
}
```

Comment: - (void)application:(UIApplication *)application didReceiveRemoteNotification:(NSDictionary *)userInfo fetchCompletionHandler:(void (^)(UIBackgroundFetchResult result))handler method called only when the user tap on the notification, i would like to call a method when the notification arrives

Comment: yes, but it also called when you receive the notification. it is called silent notifications. you can do some background work with this

Comment: and it will work if i dont use "silent notification"? because i didnt see that it work with my "normal" notification :/

Comment: i would like to notify the user when something happened, but the user not always tap on the notification, and i would like to do some work when i got a push notification

Answer (score 1):

```
  func application(application: UIApplication, didReceiveRemoteNotification userInfo: [NSObject : AnyObject])

   {
       if (state == UIApplicationState.Background || state == UIApplicationState.Inactive)
         {
            // Your Logic
         }
     }
```

//  Write this method in AppDelegate.h or AppDelegate.swift File.

Comment: this is only called when user will tap on notification

Answer (score 0):

When your push notification arrives, you can do some additional background work on didReceiveRemoteNotification delegate.

On your appDelegate.m file, add below application delegate method with dispatch_async code to run additional background execution.

```
- (void)application:(UIApplication *)application didReceiveRemoteNotification:(NSDictionary *)userInfo{


    //Background execution block
    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_DEFAULT, 0), ^{

        //Do some work if the user tap on the notification
    });
}
```

Comment: I use this delegate method, but its called only when the user tap on the notification..